# Route selection in the routing table

Tags: networking, routing

I would like to understand some basic concepts about routing. If i'm right that *-s* flag in *netcat* utility don't have any connection with *interface* column in the routing table? If i'm right that the flag only determine *src* address field in the TCP segment while route selection is always made based on *dst* address?

Answer (score 1):

> If i'm right that the flag only determine src address field in the TCP segment while route selection is always made based on dst address?

Traditionally, yes, IP routing tables are for the destination only. (On Linux, the routes can even suggest the preferred source address based on the destination.)

However, on some systems, the chosen source address *can* make a difference in routing. I haven't worked with "real" routers personally, but at least on Linux there is "policy routing" accessible via `ip rule`, which can select *different routing tables* [based on the source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-specific_routing). For example:

- `from 192.168.1.7 lookup table_for_isp_1`
- `from 192.168.4.11 lookup table_for_isp_2`
- `from all lookup default`

Each of these tables can have its own routes (including a default route), so if you used `nc -s 192.168.1.7 ...` the system would first try searching `table_for_isp_1` for a match.

This feature is often pretty much required to make [multiple network connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming) work properly.

Comment: @gravity Thx. for reply. Maybe You can then help me with some oddity. I have following routing table
> `192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.0.11    276
192.168.0.11   255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.0.11    276
192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255       On-link      192.168.0.11    276`
The strange thing is that when i remove _192.168.0.11_ route i got _"TIMEOUT"_ trying `nc -zv -s 192.168.0.11 192.168.0.11 80`. I wonder why doesn't it select _192.168.0.0_ route since _192.168.0.11_ belongs to _192.168.0.0_?

Comment: @gravity Sorry for such unreadable format, but this ultra stupid comments policy doesn't allow line breaks.

Comment: That's because it expects you to post this as a separate question, since it'll have its own answers.

Comment: @gravity Can You please try to ask my question "Route selection" i just have added?